# How to get the second block of html code with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver.get('http://www.datiopen.it/it/opendata/Mappa_delle_stazioni_ferroviarie_in_Italia')
element = driver.find_element_by_id("Tabella")
time.sleep(5)
element.click()
time.sleep(5)
a=driver.find_element_by_id('rId_48').get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(a)
```

My output:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="" aria-describedby="list_"><a title="Vedi su Google Maps" href="javascript:StatPortalOpenData.ODataUtility.openInStreetView(45.0760003999999,7.5911782);"><img alt="Vedi su Google Maps" height="25" width="25" style="vertical-align:middle" src="/sites/all/modules/spodata/metadata/viewer/multidimensional_viewer/img/streetView.png"></a></td>

<td role="gridcell" style="" class="" title="COLLEGNO" aria-describedby="list_Cccomune_608711150">COLLEGNO</td>
```

My desired output:

```
<td role="gridcell" style="" class="" title="COLLEGNO" aria-describedby="list_Cccomune_608711150">COLLEGNO</td><td role="gridcell" style="" class="" title="CITTA' METROPOLITANA DI TORINO" aria-describedby="list_Ccprovincia_1472723626">CITTA' METROPOLITANA DI TORINO</td>
```

So it is the second block of `<td> </td>`

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try this `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="COLLEGNO"]')` ?

Comment: I find it so strange that it gives you only two <tr> and not  the whole list. Are u sure that you gave us the whole output?

Comment: @EdoardoRosso Do you mean two td?

Comment: no it gave me whole output but this site does not allow me to put too much code. what I meant is  <tr> etc etc

Comment: No @Karthik it will not work I need to define it is the entry number 48 of the table that is why I used `find_element_by_id('rId_48')`

Comment: Also try to stay away from using time.sleep() use webdriver wait insteads. They tend to be much more efficient for waiting for elements to appear after page loading. Also implicitly_wait as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to target specific **row** and **cell** value you can use following `CSS selector`.

To `print the element`:

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#rId_48>td:nth-child(2)").get_attribute('outerHTML'))
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#rId_48>td:nth-child(3)").get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

OR `to print the text of the element`

```
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#rId_48>td:nth-child(2)").text)
print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#rId_48>td:nth-child(3)").text)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you selected the parent element of the `<td>` you want. Just use a css selector to get all the td elements inside it:

```
a=driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#rId_48 td')
```

Note the "s" in `find_elements...`. This returns a list of all the `<td>` elements. So the one you want should be `a[1]`.